# Парсер данных! Андроид

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Логика такая. Из другого активити мы передаем ссылку, по которой нужно парсить. Здесь мы ей вытягиваем и показываем на экране эти данные. Но почему то выкидывает ошибка, когда хочу перейти в это активити. Если закоментировать строку `new ParsePost().execute();` то все хорошо, но данных нет. Помогите пожалуйста... не могу найти ошибку! Код:

```
    package com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.group.samuliak.hpk.R;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class detailPost extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String ID = "ID";

TextView title, text;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_post);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Collapsing");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    new ParsePost().execute();

}

public class ParsePost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        String myURL = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra(ID, 0));
        parsePost(myURL);
        return null;
    }

    private void parsePost(String myURL) {
        Elements titleParse, textParse, photoParse;
        try {
            Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();
            titleParse =  doc.select("h1.page-title");
            textParse = doc.select("div.news-body p");
            photoParse = doc.select("figure.news-featured-image img");
            String myURLPhoto = photoParse.attr("src");
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(myURLPhoto).getContent();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i < textParse.size(); i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(textParse.first());
                textParse.remove(0);
            }

            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            title.setText(titleParse.text());
            text.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {}

}
```

}

Ошибки:

> 01-11 18:11:54.495 12839-12943/com.group.samuliak.hpk
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: 0
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:78)
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38)
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.parsePost(detailPost.java:55)
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.doInBackground(detailPost.java:48)
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.doInBackground(detailPost.java:44)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
>                                                                            Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 0
>                                                                               at java.net.URL.(URL.java:178)
>                                                                               at java.net.URL.(URL.java:127)
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:76)
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:38) 
>                                                                               at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.parsePost(detailPost.java:55) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.doInBackground(detailPost.java:48) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.group.samuliak.hpk.activity.detailPost$ParsePost.doInBackground(detailPost.java:44) 
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
>                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
>                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
>                                                                               at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)  01-11 18:11:54.515
>   12839-12839/com.group.samuliak.hpk W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib
>   not implemented

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки приложите.

Comment: Приложите `URL` ваш. Судя по логам он с ошибкой.

Comment: вы делаете неправильно почти все. Тут проще сказать, что правильно, чем что неправильно. Для начала идите где-нибудь почитайте, как пользоваться `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите как вы формируете `URL`:

`String myURL = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra(ID, 0));`

Метод `public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)` [возвращает](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) целочисленное значение. Соответственно в стектрейсе исключения эта проблема и указана:

> Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 0 at
>   java.net.URL

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я понял, в чем ошибка !